# Array copy using slice is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would expect that after using `distances.slice()`, I would have a copy of the array. But when I change an element of the new copy, it still changes the original array. Why?

```js
var distances = [
  ['-1', '10', '-1', '31'],
  ['10', '-1', '10', '-1'],
  ['-1', '-1', '-1', '10'],
  ['15', '6', '-1', '-1']
];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(distances, 'distances pairstop');
  var sampleDistance = distances.slice()
  sampleDistance[0][2] = ['fooo']
}
```

Comment: `slice` only does a shallow copy

Answer (score 5):

Slice produces a **shallow** copy of the array.
It says so in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

Since `distances` is an array of arryas, `sampleDistance` will be a shallow copy, meaning it will  hold refernces to the same 3 (one-dimentional) arrays. 
`sampleDistance[0][2] = ['fooo']` changes the first one-dimentional array, which is referenced both by `sampleDistance` and `distances`.

hence your bug.

Comment: To achieve a deep copy you can use `var sampleDistance = distances.map(x => x.slice())
`

Answer (score 1):

To clone an array with sub array items with indefinite depth you need a general array cloning tool like;

```
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};
```

So `distances.clone()` should just do the job fine.